# Android SQLite database is locked when pressing power button (screen off)

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a large amount of information from server and loading them in SQLite database (about 4000 rows). I'm using the following code to insert the info:

```
String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.app.myapplication/databases/";
            String DB_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
            SQLiteDatabase sqdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
            try {
                //Getting info
                sqdb.beginTransaction();
                String[] all_elements = all.split("_");
                for (int j = 0; j < all_elements .length; j++) {
                    if (all_elements [j].length() >= 1) {
                        m.setLength(0);
                        m.append("insert into .....the query");
                        m.append(");");
                        sqdb.execSQL(m.toString().replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "").replaceAll("\t", ""));

                        changeProgressMessage("Adding element " + String.valueOf(j + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(all_elements .length));
                    }
                }
                sqdb.setTransactionSuccessful();
                sqdb.endTransaction();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.d("Error",ex.toString());
                sqdb.setTransactionSuccessful();
                sqdb.endTransaction();

            }
```

The point is, when inserting the info, If I press the power button or the screen is off, The app crashes and I get an error saying that the database is locked.
Please note that I'm using another connection to the SQLite database but I'm closing it before using the second one.

```
 db.openDataBase();

                String[] array_elements = array.split("_");
                for (int i = 0; i < array_elements .length; i++) {
                    String Details = "";
                    if (!array_elements [i].isEmpty() && !array_elements [i].equals("")) {

                        mbuilder.setLength(0);
                        mbuilder.append(array_elements [i] + ",'" + helper.getdatetime() + "'");

                        db.insertelements(mbuilder.toString(), "Element");
                        changeProgressMessage("Element" + String.valueOf(i + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(array_elements .length) + " inserted");


                    }


                }
                db.close();
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Is it possible to post your logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Guys my bad, I was accessing the database in on resume method, so when turning off the screen then turning on, On resume method was called also the database method inside it which explains the crash.